# Moving from positive upper Banach density to positive upper density

Tags: ramsey-theory

Under which conditions positive upper Banach density implies positive upper or lower asymptotic density? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $ X_n $ be Bernoulli ($ p_n $) independent random variables where $ p_n $ goes to 0 sufficiently slowly.  Then the set of $ n $ where $ X_n=1$ has upper Banach density 1 but asymptotic density 0.